# The Inno Setup action I want after CreateInputQueryPage happens before. Why?

Tags: inno-setup

When Running my Inno Setup built installer, the action that I want to have happen as a result of selections in the CreateInputQueryPage happens before the CreateInputQueryPage opens and gets input from the user. What concept am I missing?

Is it that I need to use NextButtonClick?

Here is my Pascal code based on code taken from  (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp):

```
[Code]
procedure UserGroup;
Var  Page : TInputQueryWizardPage;
  GroupName : String;
  Message: String;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // Create page
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'Users Group Required', 
    'Please specify group, then click Next',
    'A Windows security group must be created.'
    );

  // Add items (False means it's not a password edit)
  Page.Add('GroupName:', False);
  Page.Values[0] := 'SomeGroup';

  // Read values into variables
  GroupName := Page.Values[0];
  if Exec('net.exe', Format( 'localgroup %s /add',[GroupName]), '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    // success 
    Message := Format('The user group %s has been added to the local machine.', [GroupName]);
    MsgBox( Message, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end
  else begin
    // failure i
    Message := Format('The installer was not able to set up the %s security group. Please do so manually. (Inno Error Code: %i)', [GroupName, ResultCode]);
    MsgBox( Message, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

But the MsgBox shows before the CreateInputQueryPage does.

Comment: It's extremely hard to debug your code when you don't post your code. It does absolutely no good to post code that you say *is similar to mine* and *then I add something like this*. If you want help with your code, **post your code**.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks.... I think I spotted something, based on your comment I double checked and I did one thing different... It will be a while to test, but I am hopeful that I found the mistake....or not...

Comment: @KenWhite Nope still broken. I have edited according to your suggestion.

Comment: Nope. Still not **your code**. Post the actual code (with the exception of the *strings changed to protect the innocent). *Then I add something like* doesn't tell us *what you actually added*; nor does it tell us *where you added it*. **Post your code.**

Comment: @KenWhite perhaps this new edit is more clear to you. My effort against this was mirely to seperate the code I was using from the examplle, from my code, and give a naritive flow to the question.

Comment: *Still* not your code. It's incomplete, as you would be able to see if it were complete and properly indented and formatted. I'm just about to the point of downvoting and voting to close this question; we shouldn't have to fight with you to provide the information we need in order to give you *free help to solve **your** problem*. Why are you making it so difficult to help you? **Post your actual, real, complete code.**

Comment: @KenWhite I wasn't quick enough and posted in the wrong order. try again.

Comment: @KenWhite do you want the entire file? That would be too huge perhaps..... but perhaps the answer is not to find my mistake but point me in the correct direction to concepts I need to learn to understand the proper use of this function better.

Comment: The `CodeDlg.iss` sample script shows you how to properly add a page (which you seem to have down), and also shows you how to properly process that page (which you're not doing at all - you seem to expect it to execute as soon as it's added). See the code in that sample in the `NextButtonClick` function for an example of how to properly deal with custom pages.

Comment: @KenWhite That is indeed the answer, thank you. I'd accept it, but alas it is a comment.